# Solution to enforce invariant for object state

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I have a problem that probably has some standard solution or a design pattern that I'm unaware of.
Suppose I have a `Rectangle` class like this:

```
class Rectangle {
public:
    void setShape(float top, float left, float width, float height);
    void setCenter(float cx, float cy);
private:
    float top, left, width, height, center_x, center_y;
}
```

Now, when a user of `Rectangle` calls `setShape`, the method will also set the center
and if the user calls `setCenter`,  the method will modify `top` and `left` accordingly, such that the center of the rectangle is consistent with it's top-left corner.

However, in a more complicated setting, it is easy to introduce a bug by setting the relevant
fields in a setter and not modifying the remaining fields such that the entire object remains consistent and makes sense.

Is there a general solution / design pattern to somehow enforce, either at compile time or at runtime, that an object will satisfy some invariant after each setter is finished?

Thanks

Comment: Write the invariant test as a member function.  Call this test(s) at the end of the setter and throw an exception if the invariant is broken.

Comment: @RichardCritten IMO, a failed invariant check should invoke `std::terminate()` (similar to `assert()`) and not a thrown exception.

Comment: @Frank good point.

Comment: I would like to add that make sure your getters/setters work well, and call them in other member functions rather than accessing the member variables directly.

Comment: Get rid of redundant data. You can remove `center_x` and `center_y` because they can be calculated from the remaining four. Or you can remove `top` and `left` because they can be calculated from the remaining four.

Comment: @Pete Becker, that's a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, removing redundant members can definitely help prevent invariant violation issues, but there are still implicit invariants worth checking in your posted code: `width` and `height` being positive numbers, for example.

In any case, how to systematically handle invariant checking is interesting regardless. Ideally we should have all the following:

- A compile-time switch to strip invariant checks from release builds
- A convention e.g. `bool test_invariant() const` member method. Any type implementing this is understood to have a checkable invariant.
- A free-floating function that defaults to that member so that arbitrary types can be opted-in, similar to `std::begin()`
- A function e.g. `check_invariant(const T&)` that stops the program if the passed object has a failed invariant.
- The ability to call `check_invariant(something)` anywhere it makes sense (e.g. in the middle of unit tests)
- A RAII wrapper to invoke `check_invariant()` on scope exits so that exceptions and early returns are handled correctly.

It sounds like a lot, but most of this can be squirreled away in a header, leaving a fairly clean API within the code proper.

With the help of a few C++20 features, we could go about it like this:

```cpp
// invariant.h

#include <concepts>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>
#include <string_view>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
  #include <intrin.h>  // for __debugbreak()
#endif

// Default to NDEBUG-driven if not explicitely set.
#ifndef MY_PROJECT_CHECK_INVARIANTS
  #ifdef NDEBUG 
    #define MY_PROJECT_CHECK_INVARIANTS false
  #else
    #define MY_PROJECT_CHECK_INVARIANTS true
  #endif
#endif

// Compile-time switch to enable/disable invariant checks
constexpr bool enable_invariant_checks = MY_PROJECT_CHECK_INVARIANTS;

// optional: Concepts, to get cleaner errors 
template<typename T>
concept HasInvariantMethod = requires(const T& x) {
  {x.test_invariant()} -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
};

template<typename T>
concept HasInvariant = requires(const T& x) {
  {test_invariant(x)} -> std::convertible_to<bool>;
};
 
// Should be overloaded for types we can't add a method to.
template<HasInvariantMethod T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr bool test_invariant(const T& obj) {
  return obj.test_invariant();
}

// Performs invariant check if they are enabled, becomes a no-op otherwise.
template<HasInvariant T>
constexpr void check_invariant(
    const T& obj, 
    std::string_view msg = {},
    std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) {
  if constexpr(enable_invariant_checks) {
    if(!test_invariant(obj)) {
      std::cerr << "broken invariant: "
              << loc.file_name() << "("
              << loc.line() << ":"
              << loc.column() << ") `"
              << loc.function_name() << "`: "
              << msg << '\n';

      // break into the ddebugger if available
      #ifdef _MSC_VER
       __debugbreak();
      #else
        // etc...
      #endif
      // Invariant failures are inherently unrecoverable.
      std::terminate();
    }
  }
}

// RAII-driven invariant checks.
// This ensures early returns and thrown exceptions are handled.
template<typename T>
struct [[nodiscard]] scoped_invariant_check {
  constexpr scoped_invariant_check(const T& obj, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) : obj_(obj), loc_(std::move(loc)) {
      // Checking invariants upon entering a scope is technically
      // redundant, but there's no harm in doing so.
      check_invariant(obj_, "entering scope", loc_);
  }

  constexpr ~scoped_invariant_check() {
      check_invariant(obj_, "exiting scope", std::move(loc_));
  }

  const T& obj_;
  std::source_location loc_;
};
```

Usage example:

```cpp
#include "invariant.h"

class Rectangle {
public:
    void setShape(float top, float left, float width, float height) {
      scoped_invariant_check check(*this);
      // ...
      top_ = top;
      left_ = left;

      // BUG! These could go negative
      width_ = width;
      height_ = height;
    }

    void setCenter(float cx, float cy) {
      scoped_invariant_check check(*this);
      // ...
      
    }

    bool test_invariant() const {
        return 
          width_ >= 0.0f &&
          height_ >= 0.0f;
    }
private:
    float top_ = 0.0f, left_ = 0.0f , width_ = 0.0f, height_ = 0.0f;
};

int main() {
  Rectangle r;

  r.setShape(1,1, -1, 12); // Bam!
}
```

Play with it live on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3ccz8PoPj).

Alternatively, if you want to keep things simple, you can approximate most of that with good-old `assert()`:

```cpp
#include <cassert>

class Rectangle {
public:
   void setShape(float top, float left, float width, float height) {
     // ...

     assert(test_invariant());
   }

   void setCenter(float cx, float cy) {
     // ...

     assert(test_invariant());
   }

private:
   bool test_invariant() const {
       return ...;
   }

   float top, left, width, height;
};
```